# How to detokenize words back to the original form in a list in Python

Tags: python

```
libOfSentences = ["Get help with the display",
                 "Display is not working properly", "I need some help"]
#removing stopwords

for i in libOfSentences:
     sentence = word_tokenize(j) #tokenize each individual word
     sentence = filter(lambda x: x not in string.punctuation, sentence) 
     cleaned_text = filter(lambda x: x not in stop_words, sentence) 

     removedStopwordsList = " ".join(cleaned_text)
```

`removedStopwordsList` has now joined the sentences back together but I want to keep it in a list. The desired output is like this:

```
["Get help display", "Display not working properly", "I need some help"]
```

I want to have `removedStopwordsList` still be a list I can loop through for example

```
removedStopwordsList[0]
```

gives me

```
"G D I"
```

right now but I want `removedStopwordsList[0]`

to output

```
"Get help display"
```

The join function is what is stopping this from occurring right now but I can't find a better workaround.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to have removedStopwordsList still be a list

Then just make it a list instead of making it a string:

```
removedStopwordsList = list(cleaned_text)
```

Although you can do this even more simply by using a list comprehension instead of calling `filter`:

```
removedStopwordsList = [x for x in sentence if x not in stop_words]
```

`map` and `filter` are great when you have a function you want to call on each element, but when you have an arbitrary expression, which you have to wrap up in `lambda` to turn into a function call, it's simpler and more readable to just use a list comprehension or generator expression.

And you can similarly simplify the previous line. So:

```
for i in libOfSentences:
    sentence = word_tokenize(j) #tokenize each individual word
    sentence = (x for x in sentence if x not in string.punctuation)
    removedStopwordsList = [x for x in sentence if x not in stop_words]
```

---

If you need to have the joined-up string around as well, that's fine; you can have a second variable:

```
removedStopwordsString = " ".join(removedStopwordsList)
```

If you really want a single object that can behave both ways, it wouldn't be *hard* to write such a class, but it would just be ugly. And under the covers, it's just going to have a self.list_of_words and self.joined_string that it delegates to anyway. So, what would be the point?

At any rate, I doubt you need to keep the string around. If you ever want to print it out, you can just `join` it on the fly:

```
print(" ".join(removedStopwordsList))
```

… or even expand it into separate printables:

```
print(*removeStopwordsList)
```

---

If you're trying to gather all of those lists into one big list, you have to actually write code to do that. Obviously if you do `removeStopwordsList = <anything>` each time through the loop, you're just replacing it each time through. You need to `append` that to some bigger list if you want to keep all those lists around. For example:

```
listOfLists = []
for i in libOfSentences:
    sentence = word_tokenize(j) #tokenize each individual word
    sentence = (x for x in sentence if x not in string.punctuation)
    removedStopwordsList = [x for x in sentence if x not in stop_words]
    listOfLists.append(removedStopwordsList)
```

And now, if you print out `listOfLists`, it'll be a list of two lists of words; `listOfLists[0]` will be the first list; `listOfLists[0][0]` will b the first word of the first list; etc.

Comment: I appreciate the response. When I print removedStopwordsList[0], I still get the first word of each sentence. How can I make it so that removedStopwordsList[0] gives me the first sentence in the list? I am still have the problem above and wanted some clarification. Thank you

Comment: @BlueButterfly Without a [mcve] that actually runs, it's pretty hard to debug your code. And I'm also not sure what you actually want to do here. Please edit the question to be more clear—include running code, and show the actual vs. desired output.